# indexing using if-else loop

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create an index for my df using a column of 0s and 1s. I want a new index number each time the loop encounters a 1.

```
x<-c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1)
index<-rep(1,20)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,index))
###
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
df$index<-ifelse(x[i]==0,index[i],index[i-1]+1)
}
```

Results produce an index column of 2's but it should be a column that looks like this...

`1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 7`

When I replace my index[i] and index[i-1]+1 to "a" and "b" I'm just getting b's back so something seems flawed with my for loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please tag the language you are using

Comment: `df$index = cumsum(df$x)`, or `cumsum(df$x) + 1` if you want it to start at 1.